# ng-click on checkbox not updating $pristine property of form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

### $pristine property of the form is not updated when the hidden text is updated for first time AngularJS

I have got a form in AngularJS and I want to know if any field of the form is updated.

when a checkbox is updated, then the corresponding `$pristine` property is not updated.

So I added a hidden text box which is bind to same `ng-model` of a checkbox.

But it is not working for the first time and works from the second time on.

The HTML code is below -

```
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

<body ng-app="formApp" ng-controller="formController">
  <div>
    <form name="myForm">
      <label>Personal Question</label>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="awesome" ng-model="formData.awesome" 
                 ng-true-value="ofCourse" ng-false-value="iWish" 
                 ng-click="onClick()"> Are you awesome?
          <input type="text" name="hidden-awesome" ng-model="formData.awesome"
                 ng-hide="true"/>
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the AngularJS code is below -

```
var formApp = angular.module('formApp', [])
.controller('formController', function($scope) {
  $scope.onClick = function() {
    alert('is myform is not modified? '+ $scope.myForm.$pristine);
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.myForm))
  };
});
```

I have my code in [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PcxWQ5Cot04WmsJ3n3Py?p=preview).

How should I handle this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `ng-change` directive instead of `ng-click`:

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="awesome" ng-model="formData.awesome" 
         ng-true-value="ofCourse" ng-false-value="iWish" 
         ̶n̶g̶-̶c̶l̶i̶c̶k̶=̶"̶o̶n̶C̶l̶i̶c̶k̶(̶)̶"̶
         ng-change="onClick()" > Are you awesome?
```

The `ng-change` directive adds a [$viewChangeListener](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$viewChangeListeners) that is invoked *after* the user operates the control.

The `ng-click` directive adds a click handler that is invoked *before* the [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) updates the model.

**Note:** Checkboxes can be focused using the <kbd>tab</kbd> key and operated with the <kbd>enter</kbd> key as well as by clicking with the mouse.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-change Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)